# Controller returns null on submit @Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following form:

```
@model proj.ViewModels.AddMenu
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{ 
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Menu.MenuName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.MenuItem.MenuItemName)

  <input type="submit" />
}
```

And this ViewModel

```
public class AddMenu
{

    public Menu Menu { get; set; }
    public MenuItem MenuItem { get; set; }
}
```

A Menu can have a MenuItem. When I submit the form, I expected to see my Addmenu model have the MenuName completed and the Addmenu.MenuItem.MenuItemName completed.

I was then going to add my menu item to my Menu (as the menu has a collection of MenuItems in it).

But both the Menu and the MenuItem from AddMenu come back null?

Does anybody know why this is the case?

Comment: What's your controller's signature look like?

Comment: Hello Brad. The controller looks like this: public ActionResult Addmenu(Addmenu menu) { menu is null} sorry for the formatting

Comment: be sure to decorate it with the HttpPost attribute too.

Comment: Could you post the Menu and MenuItem classes too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I never realised, but the model will only work when I pass them separately:

```
public ActionResult Addmenu(Menu menu, MenuItem menuItem)
{
//Model is not null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having here is that you're trying to bind textboxes to types that aren't strings, dates, integers, etc. MVC doesn't exactly know what to do with your Menu and MenuItem class. What is in these classes?

What you perhaps could consider is to create a viewmodel with two string properties, named Menu and MenuItem. In that case you'll have populated data in your postback, after which you can do what you want (map to other objects, etc.)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242579/mvc-bind-textboxfor-to-a-field-of-type-object) article contains an answer that seems quite complete to me if you're interested in reading more.