# MVC. Bind TextBoxFor to a Field of type object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Suppose the following code:

```
public class Person 
{
    public object Age { get; set;}
}
```

Inside view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { @type = "number" })
```

Now when posting the Form, the typeOf `person.Age` property is `string[1]`. Why?

Shouldn't there be some input type based, `Type` pick-up logic, when binding things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `*For` helpers with a property of type `object`. These helpers need to do type inference in order to create the right type of input with the right name and attributes. An `object` could literally be *anything*.

I'm not sure why you're using `object` for a property like `Age` (isn't that fairly obviously a `int`?). However, if you truly need to do that, I would recommend using a view model where you can define a more concrete type for the purposes of your view. Then, you can simply map the posted value back onto your `object` property.

Comment: Hmm, can this be solved using a custom DataAnnotation something like `[DataType(DataType.CreditCard)]`, or using a custom model binder ?

Comment: No. Data annotations will not help. They don't inform the type-inferencing. You *might* be able to do something with a custom model binder, but that's a very hacky way to approach it and much more complicated than simply using a view model. Really, you should be using view models even if not for this particular issue, anyways.

Comment: Thanks! This is a valid solution.